# saveAsTextFile to s3 on spark does not work, just hangs

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark

I am loading a csv text file from s3 into spark, filtering and mapping the records and writing the result to s3.

I have tried several input sizes: 100k rows, 1M rows & 3.5M rows.
The former two finish successfully while the latter (3.5M rows) hangs in some weird state in which the job stages monitor web app (the one in port 4040) stops , and the command line console gets stuck and does not even respond to ctrl-c. The Master's web monitoring app still responds and shows the state as `FINISHED`.

In s3, I see an empty directory with a single zero-sized entry `_temporary_$folder$`. The s3 url is given using the `s3n://` protocol.

I did not see any error in the logs in the web console.
I also tried several cluster sizes (1 master + 1 worker, 1 master + 5 workers) and got to the same state.

Has anyone encountered such an issue?
Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible you are running up against the 5GB object limitation of the `s3n FileSystem`.  You may be able to get around this by using `s3 FileSystem` (not `s3n`), or by partitioning your output.

---

Here's what the [AmazonS3 - Hadoop Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3) says:

> ***S3 Native FileSystem (URI scheme: s3n)**
>   A native filesystem for reading and writing regular files on S3. The advantage of this filesystem is that you can access files on S3 that were written with other tools. [...] The disadvantage is the 5GB limit on file size imposed by S3.*

...

> ***S3 Block FileSystem (URI scheme: s3)**
>   A block-based filesystem backed by S3. Files are stored as blocks, just like they are in HDFS. This permits efficient implementation of renames. This filesystem requires you to dedicate a bucket for the filesystem [...] The files stored by this filesystem can be larger than 5GB, but they are not interoperable with other S3 tools.*

...

> AmazonS3 (last edited 2014-07-01 13:27:49 by SteveLoughran)

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to add some quotes from that link in case the link breaks.

Comment: @CodeMaverick, added quotations from Hadoop Wiki

Comment: Great job! Now edited it to show you how to "cite" or "quote" your source so you don't get accused of plagiarism. What do you think?