# Spark execution occasionally gets stuck at mapPartitions at Exchange.scala:44

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark

I am running a **Spark** job on a two node standalone cluster (v 1.0.1).

Spark execution often gets stuck at the task mapPartitions at `Exchange.scala:44`.

This happens at the final stage of my job in a call to `saveAsTextFile` (as I expect from Spark's lazy execution).

It is hard to diagnose the problem because I never experience it in local mode with local IO paths, and occasionally the job on the cluster does complete as expected with the correct output (same output as with local mode).

This seems possibly related to reading from **s3** (of a ~170MB file) immediately prior, as I see the following logging in the console:

```
DEBUG NativeS3FileSystem - getFileStatus returning 'file' for key '[PATH_REMOVED].avro'
INFO  FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
DEBUG FileInputFormat - Total # of splits: 3
...
INFO  DAGScheduler - Submitting 3 missing tasks from Stage 32 (MapPartitionsRDD[96] at mapPartitions at Exchange.scala:44)
DEBUG DAGScheduler - New pending tasks: Set(ShuffleMapTask(32, 0), ShuffleMapTask(32, 1), ShuffleMapTask(32, 2))
```

The last logging I see before the task apparently hangs/gets stuck is:

```
INFO NativeS3FileSystem: INFO NativeS3FileSystem: Opening key '[PATH_REMOVED].avro' for reading at position '67108864'
```

Has anyone else experience non-deterministic problems related to reading from s3 in Spark?

Comment: Relates to a JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1568, and another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226419/saveastextfile-to-s3-on-spark-does-not-work-just-hangs

Comment: And another related question: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/SPARK-S3-LZO-input-worker-stuck-td9584.html